# How can I manipulate winforms applications using Telerik Testing Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a winform application and I want to create a testing environment using Telerik testing framework, and I want to get access, manipulate and interact with the UI elements using the Telerik framework. Is there any way to use Telerik for the winforms applications?or I have to create like a mapping for it? or some other frameworks for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A quick search came up with the answer: no. eg. https://www.telerik.com/forums/testing-windows-forms-application

Comment: There is an alternative for this ?some other framework maybe @gezzahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Here is a doc regarding Telerik testing framework that can help you is online documentation for the Testing Framework. It is a good starting point.(https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework/getting-started)

2, 3. Unfortunately you cannot use our Testing Framework for WinForms applications.

4. The Framework can be used by a tester with an intermediate knowledge of programming and automation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Coded UI tests which are part of Visual Studio Enterprise. See the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code) for more info.